# Internal server error in jersey with @Valid?

Tags: java, jersey, server, internal-server-error

```
@POST
    @Path("/new")
    @Timed
    public User storeUser(@Valid User user) throws Exception {
        return storeTheUser(user);
    }
```

Hello, I am trying to use the @Valid annotation with jersey but I keep getting the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1002)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:799)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:340)
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: is there more to the stacktrace? Like a `caused by`

Comment: Please output all exception trace.

Comment: I think I found the problem. One of the fields in the User class is a double with a @NotEmpty.Can I use it?  I followed the begging of the stack where the problem originated and I have ERROR [2015-11-13 20:07:46,742] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 1c53b90c98123930
! javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Double.

Comment: That annotation is only used for Strings and collections.